# Byzantine General Problem for multiple nodes

Tags: distributed, p2p, bitcoin, consensus, decentralized-applications

I am confused about BGP. The consensus can be achieved for the distributed network of n nodes if number of faulty nodes are less than n/2 right? Then if we follow general rules, in the following diagram, the nodes in bigger circle will try to attack, while a single node in the smaller circle will retreat.

Notations : 
Black node : Represents ordinary normal node.
Red node : Represents faulty node
Green arrow : Retreat message
Red arrow : Attack message

Why consensus is not established even if number of faulty nodes are only 3?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The consensus protocol you're describing seems broken. Whether consensus is reached depends on the algorithm you use, and it's not clear what you refer to as "general rules".

The f < n/2 bound holds for synchronous networks; in asynchronous networks the bound becomes f < n/3. In synchronous byzantine broadcast, we can in fact tolerate any number of faults.